# How to move category title above products column in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, template

In Blank theme the category name is located to the left just above the layered navigation sidebar.
I'd like to move the category name to the right, above the products column, so the side bar goes up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. In the folder `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/` is the file `catalog_category_view.xml`.
2. Copy this file to your own theme folder or module folder
   (if you dont know how to create a theme or a module take a look in the devdocs from Magento).
3. Add following line at the end of that file before the closing body tag

`<move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="category.products"/>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="category.products"/>
        <move element="category.description" destination="page.main.title" after="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```