# Magento 2.2 how to move category title to above description

Tags: magento2, category, layout, template

I'm just diving into template/block/layout customization in Magento 2.2 and I'd like to move my category title from being left aligned to being aligned above the description.

Currently it's like this:

```
_________________________________
|                               |
| Page Title                    |
|_______________________________|
|          |                    |
|(sidebar) | (main content)     |
|          |                    |
|          |                    |
|__________|____________________|
```

I'd like for it to be like this:

```
_________________________________
|          |                    |
|          | Page Title         |
|          |                    |
|(sidebar) | (main content)     |
|          |                    |
|          |                    |
|__________|____________________|
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Have you got solution ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116175/how-to-move-category-title-above-products-column-in-magento-2

Comment: Do still facing any problem @james?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1. **If you want it to affect all of your category pages for that create your own theme at below location**

`app/design/frontend/Package/theme` in that create a file with name `catalog_category_view.xml` at below location

> `app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/layout`

And put this code there in the file `catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <move element="columns.top" destination="content" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. **To just have this change in to a single category do following tasks**

Just go to you admin & traverse at below location

```
Catalog > Category > Your Category > Design
```

At there do following changes

> > - set Layout > 2 Columns with left bar
> > - Put below content at Layout Update XML
>
> ```
> <page>
>     <body>
>        <move element="columns.top" destination="content" before="-"/>
>     <body>
> </page>
> ```

If still facing some issue do mention below

> Note: Don't forget to make catch disabled when doing this task
>   otherwise perform the following command into your terminal from your
>   magento root directory
>
> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> ```

Thank You Happy Coding!

Comment: Please accept & upvote also if my answer helped you in solving your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="category.products"/>
            <move element="category.description" destination="page.main.title" after="-" />
        </body>
    </page>
```

**Please add xml code below file.**

> \app\design\frontend\Magento\theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml

Answer (score 0):

To display page title on top of sidebar and content you have to move it to `columns.top` where Category Description and Image are displayed. To move page title to `column.top` you have to override below file

> /your_magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

In this file you can use below code to move page title

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="columns.top" before="category.image"/>
```